# Difference between two measures

Tags: repeated-measures, t-test

A numerical value was generated for each of 65 samples on machine A at time T, and then on machine B and time S. I tested for a difference between the two runs using R as follows:

```
t.test(d$Run1, d$Run2, paired=T)
```

This showed a p-value of 0.26, which indicates that there is no difference between the runs, or that there is no difference between each pair of values? Is this the correct test to use?

Answer (score 0):

This post ([Which test should be used to compare two mean differences?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88409/which-test-should-be-used-to-compare-two-mean-differences)) may be of interest to you (I guess my reply should've been in a comment rather than an answer, but I am new here and I do not have enough reputation points to add a comment)