# T test for percent difference?

Tags: t-test, repeated-measures, paired-data

I am trying to figure out an appropriate statistic to analyse the difference between percent change of two conditions in a repeated measures design.
The study has a placebo condition and a treatment condition. Participants complete a single session of exercise under each condition (repeated measures crossover).

I'm trying to figure out a way to calculate a comparison of difference and p value comparing the percent difference from baseline to post exercise for the placebo vs the treatment condition.
I am struggling to figure out how I can do this, I'm not sure I can use a t test given it is percent difference rather than an absolute value, any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

A big issue with percent difference is that this is not a symmetric scale, e.g. -80% is not the inverse of +80% but of +400%. Another issue is that -100% is a hard boundary on the domain of your outcome, which is not usually accounted for in continuous tests. *If* your changes are all relatively similar in magnitude and far away from the boundaries you might just consider them as a regular continuous variable, but I wouldn't recommend doing so.

It would be better to log-transform your outcome and then take the difference (or take the log of their ratio which is the same), you then obtain log fold change which does not suffer from the above issues. You can do your inference in this log scale, and then back-transform any parameters you want to report on the fold change scale (which may be easier to interpret than its logarithm). See also [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160805/t-test-for-percentage-change) for some more discussion on the same topic.