# Covariate and DV - can they be the same?

Tags: terminology, ancova, predictor

I have two IVs (personality and teaching method) and a DV of self-esteem. I'm running a pretest/posttest ANCOVA (as I can't randomise) and am not sure if the DV and covariate can be the same. Can I use the same self-esteem scale to measure both the DV and the covariate, before and after intervention?

Comment: Could you edit your question to be more precise - now it is not totally clear what is your procedure and how does it relate to the question title...

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It's not clear, but possibly related: [Is it valid to include a baseline measure as control variable when testing the effect of an independent variable on change scores?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/15713/17230).

Comment: OK, sorry, have done.