# gain score vs. residualized change score when analysing correlates of change (NO group comparison)

Tags: interpretation, pre-post-comparison

Im interested in the relationship between change in so-called dynamic risk factors (e.g. low self-control) and recidivism, as well as the relationship between prison climate and change in dynamic risk factors. Thus, change is the IV in the first question, the DV in the second question. Dynamic risk is measured at two points of time.

In both situations, im wondering if i should use a simple difference score or a residualized change score (or using the posttest score while controlling for pretest score, respectively). I've read a bunch of articles on this topic (e.g. [this](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1167368) or [this](http://psycnet.apa.org/index.cfm?fa=search.displayRecord&uid=1983-04708-001) or [this](http://www.statisticalhorizons.com/wp-content/uploads/Allison.SM90.pdf)) as well as some other posts in this forum (e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15713/is-it-valid-to-include-a-baseline-measure-as-control-variable-when-testing-the-e) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25134/measure-score-change-over-time-while-accounting-for-baseline-differences)), but i'm still lacking a convincing solution to my specific problem (mainly, because most literature on this topic focusses on adjusting for baseline differences in group comparisons).

Following most literature, i would generally prefer using the change score, but there is one important pitfall: dynamic risk at pretest is correlated with recidivism (otherwise, it wouldnt be a risk factor), and those with high scores at pretest show larger changes than those with low scores at pretest (to which extent this amounts to regression to the mean would be another nice topic). Therefore, those exhibiting more prosocial change are also recidivating more, something which is not really meaningful to interpret. On the other hand, controlling for the baseline seems somewhat wrong to me because the fact that people with high (negative) baseline scores are more amenable to change is not simply a statistical problem, but of theoretical and contentual interest.

Comment: I can't speak to your particular study but quite generally change scores cause more problems than they solve, due to measurement error, regression to the mean, and imperfectly transforming the variable before subtraction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean simple difference scores, residualized change scores, or change scores in general?

Comment: Change scores in general.  In many settings change cannot be interpreted without reference to the starting value, so the notion of analyzing change is problematic (as opposed to predicted the final value conditioning on the initial value).  Details are at http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/ManuscriptChecklist under "Inappropriate choice of measure of change".  Look at it this way: It is statistically invalid to analyze change without conditioning on the initial value anyway (b/c of bias or power loss) and it is complex to have the initial value in 2 places in the model.

Answer (score -1):

I'm doing a similar type of study (measurement of dynamic risk factor over time and their effect on recidivism) and I think I have chosen my solution. If you z-score your IV before you run your analysis, your results will be far easier to interpret. I will be using a table where I present the difference in probability for recidivism at the mean change and then 1 std dev above and below the mean change. If you're trying to convert z-scores in SAS, here is a helpful link: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/faq/standard.htm

Comment: This does not answer the question.